# Capture Squarespace form submission data for enhanced conversions

Tags: forms, form-submit, form-fields, conversion-tracking

I'm working with a client to setup enhanced conversions for their form submission google ads conversion event. For this, I'll need to capture their email, first name and surname from the form, and pass this to Google ads hashed.

I'm setting this up via GTM but having trouble with the variable settings. I copy the CSS selector from the appropriate form field and use DOM element as the variable type but somehow this still doesn't seem to work.

Guidance from Google on enhanced conversions set up >> https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/13258081?hl=en-GB#zippy=%2Cidentify-enhanced-conversions-css-selectors-and-input-into-google-ads

I'm unsure of how to set this up so would appreciate any advice from anyone who has successfully managed to do this.

Website I'm working on >> https://www.drummingteambuilding.co.uk/

I've attached a screenshot of the variable I've set up for the first name. I've replicated this to collect the email and surname.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Gpd.png)

Any help is appreciated